# Como mostrar dos imagenes completas en un mismo tamaño de div, como behance?

Tags: javascript, html, css, django, tailwind

Resulta que estoy tratando de hacer una seccion donde se muestran varias imagenes, el formato es que el usuario previamente cargue desde un formulario las **imagenes** y la cantidad de **columnas** por **bloque/div**.

Ahora mi problema es cuando las imagenes dentro de un mismo **bloque/div** son de diferente tamaño, no se si es por diferente altura o anchura.

Lo que logre hacer es que tengan ambas el mismo tamaño todas dentro del **bloque/div** pero pierden el contenido, es decir, no se ven completas.

Ahora paso dos capturas, donde la **primera** es como me queda a mi, y la **segunda** es como me gustaria, que seria un estilo a lo que hacer **behance con las cuadriculas**.

[image: Imagen de como me queda la cuadricula a mi]

[image: Imagen de como me queda la cuadricula a behance]

Ahora les paso parte del codigo que estoy implementando!

```
<section id="content-body" class=" " style="">
    
    <input id="{{project.id}}" type="text" class="pid" style="display:none;">

    <div  class=" mt-20 mb-10 grid place-items-center" style="">

        {% for data in projectImages %}

        <div x-data="{dropdownOpen: false}" @click.outside="dropdownOpen = false"  class="relative group/cuadricula">

            <div class="grid max-w-7xl mb-3 gap-3" style=" grid-template-columns: repeat({{data.columns}}, minmax(0, 1fr)); ">
                
                {% for img in data.images.all %}
                <div class="overflow-hidden " style=" display:flex;">
                    <img id="{{img.id}}" class="object-cover w-full transition duration-300 ease-in-out hover:scale-110 click-open-modalZoomImagen" src="{{img.image.url}}" alt=""  style=""/>
                </div>
                {% endfor %}
                
            </div>

        <!-- BOTON EDITAR CUADRICULA -->
            <div @click="dropdownOpen = !dropdownOpen" class="z-10 absolute top-1 left-1   group/edit ">
                    <button :class="dropdownOpen ? 'visible' : 'invisible group-hover/cuadricula:visible' "  class="btn-editProjectImages bg-black border-0 p-4 rounded text-white hover:text-blue-700 transition ">
                        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke-width="1.5" stroke="currentColor" class="w-6 h-6 ">
                            <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" d="M16.862 4.487l1.687-1.688a1.875 1.875 0 112.652 2.652L6.832 19.82a4.5 4.5 0 01-1.897 1.13l-2.685.8.8-2.685a4.5 4.5 0 011.13-1.897L16.863 4.487zm0 0L19.5 7.125" />
                        </svg>  
                    </button>
                    <div :class="dropdownOpen ? 'top-full opacity-100 visible' : 'invisible opacity-0' " class="border-light shadow-card absolute left-0 z-10 mt-2  rounded border-0 bg-black text-white py-1 transition-all ">
                        <a href="{% url 'project-images-edit' p_pk=project.pk pk=data.pk %}" class="text-body-color hover:bg-primary hover:text-primary block py-2 px-5 text-base font-semibold hover:bg-opacity-5 w-full hover:text-blue-700">
                        Edit
                        </a>
                        <a href="{% url 'project-images-delete' p_pk=project.pk pk=data.pk %}" class="text-body-color hover:bg-primary hover:text-primary block py-2 px-5 text-base font-semibold hover:bg-opacity-5 w-full hover:text-blue-700">
                            Delete
                        </a>
                    </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        {% endfor %}  

    </div>
</section>
```

Y aca una parte de la hoja de estilo

```
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}


#main-content{ min-height: 100vh; margin:0; }

#navbar{ min-height:50px; z-index: 1;}

#main-content{ display:flex; flex-direction:column; }
#content-body{ flex:1; }

#footer{ min-height:50px;}
```

Desde ya muchas gracias! Espero que me logren comprender y ayudar.
Cualquier cosa si necesitan mas detalles, lo paso!

Comment: `object-fit: cover` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit

Answer (score 1):

Actualizo el codigo html-django y el css.

Ademas adjunto foto de como quedo y cual es mi nuevo problema!

```
<section id="content-body" class=" " style="">
    
    <input id="{{project.id}}" type="text" class="pid" style="display:none;">

    <div  class=" mt-20 mb-10 grid place-items-center" style="">

        {% for data in projectImages %}

        <div x-data="{dropdownOpen: false}" @click.outside="dropdownOpen = false"  class="relative group/cuadricula">

            <div class="wrapper-container max-w-7xl mb-3 gap-3">
                
                {% for img in data.images.all %}
                <div class="block-container">
                    <img id="{{img.id}}" class="transition duration-300 ease-in-out hover:scale-110 click-open-modalZoomImagen" src="{{img.image.url}}" alt=""  style=""/>
                </div>
                {% endfor %}
                
            </div>

        <!-- BOTON EDITAR CUADRICULA -->
            <div @click="dropdownOpen = !dropdownOpen" class="z-10 absolute top-1 left-1   group/edit ">
                
                    <button :class="dropdownOpen ? 'visible' : 'invisible group-hover/cuadricula:visible' "  class="btn-editProjectImages bg-black border-0 p-4 rounded text-white hover:text-blue-700 transition ">
                        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke-width="1.5" stroke="currentColor" class="w-6 h-6 ">
                            <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" d="M16.862 4.487l1.687-1.688a1.875 1.875 0 112.652 2.652L6.832 19.82a4.5 4.5 0 01-1.897 1.13l-2.685.8.8-2.685a4.5 4.5 0 011.13-1.897L16.863 4.487zm0 0L19.5 7.125" />
                        </svg>  
                    </button>
                    <div :class="dropdownOpen ? 'top-full opacity-100 visible' : 'invisible opacity-0' " class="border-light shadow-card absolute left-0 z-10 mt-2  rounded border-0 bg-black text-white py-1 transition-all ">
                        <a href="{% url 'project-images-edit' p_pk=project.pk pk=data.pk %}" class="text-body-color hover:bg-primary hover:text-primary block py-2 px-5 text-base font-semibold hover:bg-opacity-5 w-full hover:text-blue-700">
                        Edit
                        </a>
                        <a href="{% url 'project-images-delete' p_pk=project.pk pk=data.pk %}" class="text-body-color hover:bg-primary hover:text-primary block py-2 px-5 text-base font-semibold hover:bg-opacity-5 w-full hover:text-blue-700">
                            Delete
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    
                
            </div>
        </div>
        {% endfor %}  

    </div>
</section>
```

```
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

#main-content{ min-height: 100vh; margin:0; }

#navbar{ min-height:50px; z-index: 1;}

#main-content{ display:flex; flex-direction:column; }
#content-body{ flex:1; }

#footer{ min-height:50px;}

.wrapper-container{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    
}

.block-container {
    display: flex;
    max-width: auto;
}

.block-container img {
    width: auto;    
    height: auto;
}
```

[image: como queda]

Ahora mi problema como podran ver es en las tres primeras imagenes!

Voy a seguir intentado solucionarlo, desde ya gracias!